# Count total students actively studying during date range

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking to get one output showing the total count of students actively studying in each year in a user defined range.

for eg DB Structure

| StudentId | Course | StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | BSc Maths | 2012-01-01 | 2015-01-01 |
| 2 | BSc English | 2014-01-01 | 2017-01-01 |

If the user defines actively studying between '2013' and '2016' the output i would like to get is this;

| YEAR | Student_Count |
| --- | --- |
| 2013 | 1 |
| 2014 | 2 |
| 2015 | 2 |
| 2016 | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a years table to do this.

Here am generating years table through `Recursive CTE`. You can create a `physical` years table and use it instead of recursive CTE.

```
DECLARE @max_yr INT = (SELECT Max(Year(EndDate)) yr FROM   yourtable);

WITH cte
     AS (SELECT Min(Year(StartDate)) yr
         FROM   yourtable
         UNION ALL
         SELECT yr + 1
         FROM   cte
         WHERE  yr < @max_yr)
SELECT a.yr as [YEAR],
       Count(1) as [Student_Count]
FROM   cte a
       JOIN yourtable b
         ON a.yr BETWEEN Year(b.StartDate) AND Year(b.EndDate)
            AND a.yr BETWEEN 2013 AND 2016
GROUP  BY a.yr
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, it certainly worked for me - obviously @startYear and @endYear would be replaced by your own variables but I've left them in so you understand how the code is working:

```
Create Table #Temp2 ([YEAR] int, Student_Count int)

Declare @startYear int = '2013',
        @endYear int = '2016'

while (@startYear <= @endYear)
Begin
    Insert into #Temp2
    Select @startYear [YEAR], count(studentId)
    from table
    where Cast(Cast(@startYear as varchar) as date) between StartDate and EndDate
    Set @startYear = @startYear + 1
End

Select * from #Temp2
```